# Mysql multi request at same time

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, process, web

I have a Ubuntu-server. It is running Mysql & Apache. I have several request at same time. I I saw processes, by top command. I have 10 Apache process and always one process for Mysql.
I understood, sometimes on high traffic conditions, insert in database can`t be done.
I think if system creates several process for Mysql, the problem will be solved. How can i do that?

Comment: Using a single process to handle all requests or forking a new process for each request can not always be controlled by the user unless the software supports multiple operation mode.

Answer (score -1):

Your question is based on a misunderstanding. More processes would just slow things down with inter-process synchronization.

Comment: that is right! more processes make things slow but distribute resources to more than one user. it has benefits like prevents lost Mysql request.

Comment: @David Schwartz: Not always!

Comment: @Khaled I didn't say it always does. I'm talking about the OP's specific case.